# Is there any way to skip "Off The Hook"

Tags: splatoon-2

In Splatoon 2 when you start up the game from the home screen it will always take you to the in game TV show "Off The Hook". It forces you to watch the entire thing. Even worse, if you open it back on the same day you will have to watch the entire thing again. They might add this it a future update but, Is there any way to skip "Off The Hook"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on multiple complaints and no offered solutions (other than [mashing the A button to get through it as quickly as possible](https://www.reddit.com/r/splatoon/comments/6p92i8/comment/dknhigt) or just [not turning your game off ever](https://www.gamefaqs.com/switch/200279-splatoon-2/answers/468697-can-you-skip-off-the-hook-cutsecene)), there does not appear to be a way to **skip** it entirely (currently).

[Here's one such example of this kind of complaint](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/social/questions/detail/qid/69569/~/splatoon-2-is-a-great-game%2C-by-needs-much-improvement.):

> Let us skip the Off the Hook intro every time you turn the game on. Some people may enjoy it, and they will be able to sit through it - let everyone else skip it. Even mashing A is not enough because you still have to sit through pauses and marina spinning the disc and showing all 6 maps which can easily be checked in the menu.

Answer (score 5):

If you turn on Airplane Mode, you can skip "Off the Hook" when you boot up the game.

This is only useful though if you want to play single-player mode or check out your gear because once you turn off Airplane Mode and connect to the internet, Off the Hook will play once it's connected. Like Vemonus says, the only thing you can do is never close the game; you can leave it sleep mode, but actually closing the app won't work.

Ref: https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/6pt543/tip_start_splatoon_2_in_airplane_mode_to_skip_the/

Comment: Verified this as of 4/6/2020